# Facebook url scrape failing with internal 500 error

Tags: facebook-graph-api

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update it is possible to do a 'POST' on ?id=url&scrape=true to refresh the url object in Facebook cache.

This is working fine and the object attributes are getting refreshed with the last scraped time changing when the url is viewed thru the Facebook debugger.

However the API call to scrape always fails with a 500 internal error and I am keen to avoid this error from happening. I have tried to several combination of using POST fields and with/without encoding the query parameters. But nothing has helped.

Anybody else having this problem and any help is highly appreciated.

I am using graph api version - v2.5

Comment: Open up a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: I have filled a few bug reports (along with copious details) - but not once received a useful response/resolution. I have given up on filing bug reports since. Have things changed recently ?